# did you know ...?

Tags: questions, quotation-marks

Should I use an interrogation mark in the following examples?

> Did you know that…?
>      ...in Finland, there is only 1 mandatory test, PISA, taken when children are 16 ?
>      ...in Brazil an estimated one-quarter of children do not attend school?
>      ...in the sub-Saharan, 11.07 million children leave school before finishing their primary
>         education ? In South and West Asia, that number reaches 13.54 million .
>      ...in Cambodia, only an estimate of 45% of the students finishes elementary school ?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Why do you think you might need quotation marks? Are they direct quotes? You might also be interested in [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister site, which is a great site for basic English questions.

Comment: Interrogation mark = question mark, not quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the interrogation mark (usually called a "question mark," in my dialect) at the end of "Did you know that...?", leaving only the interrogation marks at the ends of the list items.

When I read a list like this, I imagine the ellipses (... marks) as drops of glue that will be used to stick pieces of a sentence together. The pieces

> Did you know that...
>
> - ...in Brazil an estimated one-quarter of children do not attend school?

stick to each other

> Did you know that ... in Brazil an estimated one-quarter of children do not attend school?

and become a complete sentence.

> Did you know that in Brazil an estimated one-quarter of children do not attend school?

---

If there were a question mark at the end of "Did you know that...", the pieces wouldn't fit together correctly. The pieces

> Did you know that...?
>
> - ...in Brazil an estimated one-quarter of children do not attend school?

would try to stick to each other

> Did you know that... ? ...in Brazil an estimated one-quarter of children do not attend school?

but the interrogation mark would be in the way, floating strangely in the middle of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If you have derived the information from a specific source or sources, it is appropriate to put the information in quotations and cite your source(s).